# How to make a search in scrollview and be able to get next indexOf?

Tags: android, search, scrollview, indexof

I have a editText and a search button, Now it just shows the first results.

But I want to be able to press the search button again and then show the next indexOf. How can I do this ?

```
public void searchMethod(final String search) {
        int i = mTextCurrentArticle.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase().trim());
        if (i == -1) {
            mEditTextSearch.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            //  String cap = search.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + search.substring(1);
            //i = mTextCurrentArticle.indexOf(cap);
        } else {
            mEditTextSearch.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
      //  int line = mTextViewCurrentArticle.getLayout().getLineForOffset(i);
        Layout layout = mTextViewCurrentArticle.getLayout();
        mScrollView.scrollTo(0, layout.getLineTop(layout.getLineForOffset(i)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the overloaded version of `indexOf` which takes a starting index for the search and pass the original index like this:

```
int i = mTextCurrentArticle.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase().trim());
int nextPosition = mTextCurrentArticle.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase().trim(), i+1);
```

**EDIT**:
If you need to cycle through subsequent positions then just make the index `i` a global variable and initialize it to `-1`

then inside your `searchMethod` use

```
i = mTextCurrentArticle.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase().trim(), i+1);
```

This will ensure that it returns the first position when called for the first time and then gives the next position when called subsequently

Comment: Yeah, thanks! But I already figured that out. The problem is how to use it with the next click on the button. I already tried making an Int that increased with every click, but it didn't work as I wanted.